# Select the normalized first row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I select the normalized first row in sql server? Suppose I have this table:

```
A   B
1   5
1   2
1   4
2   7
2   3
2   3
```

And I want the output to be:

```
A   B
1   3       = 5 - 2 (first(B) - min(B) when A = 1)
2   4       = 7 - 3 (first(B) - min(B) when A = 2)
```

Comment: how do you define *first* B?

Comment: whats happening to your third and 6th row?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I am assuming the table is as is. So `first B` is whatever the value comes first for each group of A.

Comment: @Psidom : Is there any `identity` column in your table? Other wise how to know which is first and second values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `first_value` and `min` window functions. (`somecol` should be changed to the column that specifies ordering in each group).

```
select distinct A,first_value(B) over(partition by A order by somecol)-min(B) over(partition by A)
from tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I get the idea. Is there any way to select a random value from column B instead of the first value?

Comment: you can use [`rand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) with a seed in `order by`.